# How to avoid density plot being too ragged?

Tags: plotting, precision-and-accuracy

I have a density plot as below:-

```
v = {2, 3};
w = {4, 6};
DensityPlot[Exp[-w.Abs[v - {x, y}]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 7}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the boundary of the white area is so ragged, while theoretically speaking it should be smooth (that can be expected, as you can see a smooth plot when you try to remove the `Exp` from the function).

I tried to fix it by applying a higher `WorkingPrecision` in `DensityPlot`, but it doesn't help. Are there any other ways to increase the density of the plot's grid?

I don't want to remove the `Exp` from the function. Is it possible to add `Exp` to the color scale mapping instead?

Or there are other ways to fix?

Many thanks!

Comment: More `PlotPoints`?

Comment: `DensityPlot[Exp[-w.Abs[v - {x, y}]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 7}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5, PlotPoints -> 150]`

Comment: Also, additionally to what others commented `PlotRange->All` can help getting rid of the clipped white area in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. @ThiesHeidecke May I ask why can `PlotRange->All` get rid of that?

Comment: @HMC Sure! Usually Mathematica uses a heuristic to determine what is a useful value range to plot as opposed to plot the full range of all assumed values (think a function with singularities like `1/(x-1)` and how it would give a useless plot by trying to plot the infinite range). In some cases the heuristic does cut off interesting parts of the function that were actually useful and not infinite, such as in your functions case. In the case of `DensityPlot` that means the values get clamped before they are fed to the `ColorFunction` giving the overexposed clamped look. (1/2)

Comment: `PlotRange->All` forces plotting functions to use the full range of all assumed values of the function. When you know your function has a finite value range and you want a no clipping, tight fitting plot range this is a useful option. (2/2)

Comment: I think it's easier to understand with `Plot` than `DensityPlot`. Compare e.g. `Plot[ArcTan[x]/(2+2x+x^2),{x,0,2}]` vs. `Plot[ArcTan[x]/(2+2x+x^2),{x,0,2}, PlotRange->All]`. For me the first plot gives a plotrange of `{0.0471073,0.159308}`, which clips parts at the bottom whereas with the `PlotRange->All` option we get `{2.04082*10^(-8), 0.159308}`, which includes the beginning of the curve and doesn't clip anything off.

Comment: You can also see the effect more clearly when you replace `DensityPlot` with `Plot3D` in your example.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke Many thanks for your kind explanation. `Plot3D` really tells a good story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The white part of your plot is a peak that mathematica cuts off unless `PlotRange -> All` is added.

Transforming the color map as you mention works.
To do that we need to extract the range of the function:

```
lims = {};
With[{v = {2, 3}, w = {4, 6}},
  DensityPlot[Exp[-w.Abs[v - {x, y}]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 7},
               ColorFunction -> ((lims = MinMax[{lims, #}]; 0) &),
                ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All];
  Log[lims]]
```

> {-36., -0.14285714}

```
With[{v = {2, 3}, w = {4, 6}, cols = ColorData[ColorData["Gradients"][[6]]]},
  DensityPlot[Exp[-w.Abs[v - {x, y}]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 7},
               ColorFunction -> (cols[Rescale[Log[#], Log[lims]]] &),
                ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask what `lims` and `((lims = MinMax[{lims, #}]; 0) &)` are doing?